# Is there an implementation of collective signature for anonymous signing?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, anonymous, voting-system

I want to sign anonymously with my private key combined with a collective signature. So the signature will only prove that it was made by somebody who participated in the collective signature.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com), without involving programming.

Comment: On crypto you could ask for the more particular name of the scheme. Looking for implementations is off topic there as well.

Comment: This is what I initially did and they marked it as off-topic as well https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/61753

Comment: Asking for software is off topic on both sites. That's why I said that you could ask for a name of the scheme rather than an implementation. What do you expect, that an implementation suddenly pops up by asking on SE?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I expect a response like this: You can inspect how BlaBla signing algorithm works, also HelloWorld public-private key in combination with FooBar signing verification matches what you described in your scheme.